# Extracting(not reading) a large gzip file with Python

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a python script that is automating/coordinating the transfer and processing of several large gzip files. I need to be able to unzip them (like running `gunzip file.log.gz` in a shell), but don't need to (or want to) read them in - they will be passed to another command line tool that needs unzipped files.

The problem is, the gzip module seems to only care about reading gzipped files into python. I have tried using subprocess.Popen to call gunzip on the file, but that doesn't work either as i get errors from not calling it from a shell, or any number of other errors from calling it outside a shell (yes, I have tried using shell=True in Popen).

I'm starting to pull my hair out here as this should be a relatively simple operation, and I have searched high and low for the answer. Again, I don't care about ever reading the content of the file into Python, and opening the archive and writing out line-by-line is too slow (the files are about 6-8GB compressed).

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is perfect for your use case. It makes shell-like parts of your python script so much simpler to handle.

You can run `gunzip` like:

```
from plumbum.cmd import gunzip
gunzip(filename)
```

And if the second command, which takes the unzipped file, supports reading from stdin (e.g. indicated by the conventional `-` argument), you can use a pipe, instead of unzipping the file:

```
from plumbum.cmd import zcat
(zcat[filename] | second_command['-'])()
```

Comment: THIS!!! A thousand thank you's! Not only does this do exactly what I need it to, but I've already started integrating it into the rest of my code!

Answer (score 0):

```
archive = tarfile.open(YourGZName, mode='r:gz')
archive.extractall()
```

Since TarFile supports .gz files this will extract them happily.

Comment: .. isn't the file `.gz`, not `.zip`?

Comment: Exactly. This functionality works for .zip files, but I am working with GZ files :-(

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully`